# How do I make my java code search only for a to z and 0 to 9

Tags: java, encoding, split, char

1. My java code takes almost 10-15minutes to run (Input file is 7200+ lines long list of query). How do I make it run in short time to get same results?
2. How do I make my code to search only for aA to zZ and 0 to 9??
3. If I don't do #2, some characters in my output are shown as "?". How do I solve this issue?

   ```
   // no parameters are used in the main method
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   // assumes a text file named test.txt in a folder under the C:\file\test.txt
   Scanner s = null;
   BufferedWriter out = null;
   try {
       // create a scanner to read from the text file test.txt
       FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\user\\query.txt");
       DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
       // Write to the file
       out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\user\\outputquery.txt"));

       // keep getting the next String from the text, separated by white space
       // and print each token in a line in the output file
       //while (s.hasNext()) {
       //  String token = s.next();
       //  System.out.println(token);
       //  out.write(token + "\r\n");
       //}
       String strLine="";
       String str="";

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {

               str+=strLine;
               }
              String st=str.replaceAll(" ", "");
              char[]third =st.toCharArray();
             System.out.println("Character     Total");
             for(int counter =0;counter<third.length;counter++){
                 //String ch= "a";
                char ch= third[counter];
             int count=0;
             for ( int i=0; i<third.length; i++){
                // if (ch=="a")
                 if (ch==third[i])
             count++;
           }
           boolean flag=false;
           for(int j=counter-1;j>=0;j--){
               //if(ch=="b")
               if(ch==third[j])
           flag=true;
           }
           if(!flag){
           System.out.println(ch+"                  "+count);
           out.write(ch+"                  "+count);
           }
           }



       // close the output file
       out.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       // print any error messages
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
   // optional to close the scanner here, the close can occur at the end of the code
   finally {
       if (s != null) {
           // close the input file
           s.close();
       }
           }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For something like this I would NOT recommend java though it entirely possible it is much easier with GAWK or something similar. GAWK also has java like syntax so its easy to pick up. You should check it out.

Answer (score 0):

SO isn't really the place to ask such a broad how-do-I-do-this-question but I will refer you to the following page on [regular expression and text match in Java](http://javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/string_matches.shtml). Also, check out the [Javadocs for regexes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

If you follow that link you should get what you want, else you could post a more specific question back on SO.

Comment: These chars are shown as question marks in servlet html file? why
»                  1
ї                  1
Г                  14
¶                  4
¤                  4
Ї                  1
ў                  1